# is this approach to Flask routing reasonable?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am making every path lead to index.html, since it is a single page app. I made a blueprint called mod and put all the restul api there using flask-restful

```
@mod.route('/')
@mod.route('/<path:p>')
def home(p=0):
    return render_template('index.html')
```

is this right way to do it?
I am little concerned about p=0 part.
the variable p is never used, but has to be there since it has to receive path variable p

Comment: `p=0` shouldn't matter if you are never using the variable `p`, but might this logic be implemented in the server config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routing is certainly reasonable.

A more simple/readible way of doing it might be:

```
@mod.route('/')
@mod.route('/<path>')
def home(*args, **kwargs):
    return render_template('index.html')
```

From an efficiency standpoint its probably better to handle this entirely on the webserver (nginx/apache/whatever).